# How to correctly add ENV["SECRET_KEY"BASE"] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment

I am having a difficult time setting up Rails 4.2 in production on a VM running on passenger and nginx, and not using RVM or anything similar.

I got `Incomplete response received from application` and looking in the nginx error log it said something about `missing secret_key_base` and `secret_key` although there is no reference to that last one any where in the config directory.

I ran `export SECRET_KEY_BASE='...'` and in `rails c production` `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` displays the key but after restarting nginx I still get the same error.

Placing the key directly in secrets solved that problem but is there an actual way to do this correctly?

**Solution:**

The solution that worked for me is to place `export SECRET_KEY_BASE="<string obtained from rake secret>"` in .bashrc

If you use `rbenv`, there is another solution below in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) you can add the [`rbenv-vars`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars) plugin and add a `.rbenv-vars` file containing (and don't check that into your repo)

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE='...'
```

other solution is to add the the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` manually to the `secrets.yml` file and also ignore that file from your repo.

a third answer that saw mentioned is adding

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE='...'
```

to one of these files `.bashrc` `.bash_profile` `.profile`

Comment: Great but personally I prefer the rbenv method

Comment: Well I have no use for rbenv or rvm. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your `config/secrets.yml` should have something like

```
development:
  secret_key_base: f91fe2e2e4a9bf8f8b6aa1c296bb9ec10f2bc91c08965176a642ea0927400651ea993512f83d9823bcc046555e40b8c257f5f19fab8c59b5a02c9d230a369fe7

test:
  secret_key_base: c116ac7c8f69018d1f4e10f632cac7a22348f0bd8ed8f21ca45460574d2f501f248418bc888e31556e16ba3ab58c3a7cba027140097abe3f511dddf6625fa8cd

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

To set `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, first you'll need to generate it with

```
rake secret
```

Then take that output and edit your `/etc/environment` (depending on your distro, assuming Ubuntu here) and place it as such

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=...
```

Restart your server and you should be gravy